# Products Disappearing From Search Results

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch, magento2.4, elasticsearch

Magento Version: v2.4.1-p1 
Elasticsearch Version: v7.10

Products are disappearing from search results on our site. When reviewing the exception.log we are seeing the following error messages:

> main.CRITICAL: {"error":{"root_cause":[],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"","phase":"fetch","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[],"caused_by":{"type":"aggregation_execution_exception","reason":"Merging/Reducing
> the aggregations failed when computing the aggregation
> [product_attribute_code] because the field you gave in the
> aggregation query existed as two different types in two different
> indices"}},"status":500} {"exception":"[object]
> (Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\ServerErrorResponseException(code:
> 500):
> {"error":{"root_cause":[],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"","phase":"fetch","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[],"caused_by":{"type":"aggregation_execution_exception","reason":"Merging/Reducing
> the aggregations failed when computing the aggregation
> [certification_ltf_dhv_bucket] because the field you gave in the
> aggregation query existed as two different types in two different
> indices"}},"status":500} at
> /vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:665)"}
> []

Does anyone know how to resolve this type of issue?

Comment: Can you share your elastic search config?

Comment: Hi @joeyoung, Sure. See https://www.dropbox.com/s/dpkgi0yzmsp3kft/Screenshot%202021-05-24%20at%2008.14.40.png?dl=0

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check **certification_ltf_dhv_bucket** attribute in Magento admin. As per the error, Maybe something wrong with this attribute. Check this attribute type in attribute config or trying to create again this attribute or try to delete the attribute.